# how to add two skrollr triggers to one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#top">Hello</a></li>
<li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#process" data-0="color:white;" data-top-top="color:blue;" data-anchor-target="#portfolio">Process</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contactme">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This code currently changes the text color on my navigation when I reach the div #portfolio. Is there any way I can add another trigger with a different data-anchor-target? To the same button I might add.

Comment: No, but want is it that you want to achieve? You could for example use the wrapping `<li>` and add more keyframes to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the value of attribute on basis of some JavaScript functionality, define that function in 'render' in init();

```
render: function(data){
  var flag = true; // Here goes your logic to choose if you want to change the attribute
  if(flag) document.getElementById('blue').setAttribute('data-anchor-target', '#blue');
}
```